# How can I fix this composer.phar install error in Windows 10?

Tags: php, composer-php

I've been googling this for half an hour and nothing's working. I've got PHP added to my windows path variable, and everytime I run this:

```
php composer.phar install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

I get this

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'unable to open phar for reading "composer.phar"' in composer.phar:23
Stack trace:
#0 composer.phar(23): Phar::mapPhar('composer.phar')
#1 {main}
  thrown in composer.phar on line 23
```

I'm CD'd into the folder it's in, I've tried specifying that folder in the command, nothing's working, neither does

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

edit: Ok I signed out and back in after trying the windows exe installer, seems it's installed now but only globally, I still don't have the vendor/bin directory I need in my specific project, still fails when I try and run php composer.phar install

Comment: Have you try the native installer? https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe one click installation, no hassle and composer will be a command by itself, without invoking php.

Comment: Tried it, no dice. :/ I have no idea what's going on, I'm working on a git repository, the website doesn't work without composer, it was working fine recently then I tried to run a command and it doesn't work so I wiped my repository and re-cloned, now it won't reinstall